# Using Google Authenticator in a non-google android application

Tags: android, security, google-authenticator

I want to use Google Authenticator as one of the security lock in my application.  I want to know if there are public APIs available to use Google Authenticator for this purpose.   It's a non-google android application which does not need a google account.

Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. You don't need APIs, the Authenticator is completely [open source](http://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator/source/checkout), and doesn't need to talk to Google servers. There's also a convenient PAM if you're doing straightforward auth. Essentially, you need to get a secret key from the auth module that you enter into the phone app, and you're good to go.

See [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/121650/how-to-secure-ssh-with-google-authenticators-two-factor-authentication/) for an example of using it to second factor ssh.

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for the reply.  The link definitely seems useful and clears some doubts of using google-authenticator.  However,  I am still not sure how in the android application that I am developing can I integrate this module.  As per the example, to enable google-authenticator for ssh, the sshd has been modified with this addition:  **auth required pam_google_authenticator.so**  How will I be able to execute this from an Android app?  What else will I be required to register my application with google-authenticator?

Comment: I found how it is to be done.  Thanks to the blog: http://thegreyblog.blogspot.in/2011/12/google-authenticator-using-it-in-your.html and article https://weblogs.java.net/blog/evanx/archive/2012/11/07/google-authenticator-thus-enabled.  This cleared my doubts of using google-authenticator as a client.  I could implement an application that creates secret key/QR Code which then I can add to the google-authenticator against a username.

Comment: @Keya links are down.